# Add another element to an already filled index in arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a studentgradeprogram, I want to make it possible so that the user can set multiple grades for the students, but only the first input value is registered, i want all of them to be registered. And when I want to printout the studentgradelist, I want it to show all of the students with their all grades in one row.
Like this:

> Hanna grade: 5, 6, 10, 4.
>   Emelie grade: 6, 7, 8, 3.

Is it possible to create a gradelist for each instance of the class student?
(Im using an arrayList)

```
public void register() {

    System.out.println("Studentname: ");
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Grade: ");
    int grade = keyboard.nextInt();


    Student h1 = new Student(name, grade);

    gradeList.add(h1);
    System.out.println(name + " grade: " + grade);

    System.out.println("");
    keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Consider using `HashMap` (of lists) instead of List

Comment: Why not make grade an array of ints or an arraylist of ints instead of a single int?

Comment: Yeah, or just a string ... Like `new Student("Jane", "3,7,5,4,8")`

Comment: If I get it, for each student, you want to remember all the grades (and be able to display them), but in addition have a property like `student.RegisteredGrade` which will retrieve the first grade. Is that correct?